# JSON grouping in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON and I want to display that in a table using AngularJs.

```
[{"id":"e2500e80a9d3a2e57092ac1e76fac377","doc":{"title":"star","name":"Sam","day":"01","count":3}},{"id":"85016ca713119cee46a59191de5d0d89","doc":{"title":"star","name":"David","day":"01","count":5}},{"id":"033f3022576b97d3147a1c016d9aa473","doc":{"title":"Fav","name":"Jan","day":"01","count":3}},{"id":"b31a89b2852e3096bb1c8a139c0a799e","doc":{"title":"Fav","name":"Haze","day":"01","count":3}},{"id":"67222f12e79d3164a2e235712859bc91","doc":{"title":"Soup","name":"Santi","day":"02","count":1}},{"id":"1870139670d500e4b3a546dc98df5d41","doc":{"title":"Soup","name":"Cool","day":"02","count":2}},{"id":"6866bc4fd079f67d110400fe64f497bd","doc":{"title":"Fav","name":"Lettuce","day":"02","count":2}},{"id":"31f3066f80d45ff939d07b13fa1ea063","doc":{"title":"Fav","name":"Campagnola","day":"02","count":3}},{"id":"2c41f42808252fec6a8572f635cda808","doc":{"title":"star","name":"Fettuccine","day":"02","count":4}}]
```

Please anyone help me to list the above JSON like a table format.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Cz8.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the StackOverflow! 
Have you tried *anything*? Any examples? Or do you simply want someone to make it for you? :-)

Comment: Please provide some your code which you tried and not successful with that. So it will be easy for someone to guide/help you. Or do you expect ready made code for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

**I have created a Fiddle with you json, please go through it.You can far minimize it.**

```js
 var myList=
            [{"id":"e2500e80a9d3a2e57092ac1e76fac377","doc":{"title":"star","name":"Sam","day":"01","count":3}},{"id":"85016ca713119cee46a59191de5d0d89","doc":{"title":"star","name":"David","day":"01","count":5}},{"id":"033f3022576b97d3147a1c016d9aa473","doc":{"title":"Fav","name":"Jan","day":"01","count":3}},{"id":"b31a89b2852e3096bb1c8a139c0a799e","doc":{"title":"Fav","name":"Haze","day":"01","count":3}},{"id":"67222f12e79d3164a2e235712859bc91","doc":{"title":"Soup","name":"Santi","day":"02","count":1}},{"id":"1870139670d500e4b3a546dc98df5d41","doc":{"title":"Soup","name":"Cool","day":"02","count":2}},{"id":"6866bc4fd079f67d110400fe64f497bd","doc":{"title":"Fav","name":"Lettuce","day":"02","count":2}},{"id":"31f3066f80d45ff939d07b13fa1ea063","doc":{"title":"Fav","name":"Campagnola","day":"02","count":3}},{"id":"2c41f42808252fec6a8572f635cda808","doc":{"title":"star","name":"Fettuccine","day":"02","count":4}}];
            var myList1=myList;
            
for(var i=0;i<myList1.length;i++){
myList1[i].title = myList1[i].doc.title;
myList1[i].name = myList1[i].doc.name;
myList1[i].day = myList1[i].doc.day;
myList1[i].count = myList1[i].doc.count;
delete myList1[i].doc;
}



// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
 function buildHtmlTable() {
     var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);
 
     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var row$ = $('<tr/>');
         for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
             var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
 
             if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }
 
             row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
         }
         $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
     }
 }
 
 // Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
 // Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
 // all records
 function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
 {
     var columnSet = [];
     var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');
 
     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var rowHash = myList[i];
         for (var key in rowHash) {
             if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
                 columnSet.push(key);
                 headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
             }
         }
     }
     $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);
 
     return columnSet;
 }
```

```css
th {
    font-weight : bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onLoad="buildHtmlTable()">
<table id="excelDataTable" border="1">
 </table>
</body>
```